# Adding a custom legend on mapbox - displays wacky

Tags: legend, mapbox

I am a designer, new to mapbox. (So, I may need things explained to me like I'm a four-year old, pretty please).

I created a map with labels using their plain editor (not Studio) and placed it on my page [here](http://mcshanedev.com/canet/).

I want to add a custom legend, possibly in a custom position. I tried using their example, but my map doesn't even show up at all. When I comment out mapbox's CSS link ref in the head, it almost works, but shows all wacky. [See that one here](http://mcshanedev.com/canet/index-legend1.html).

Here's the added HEAD code per mapbox's legend example that I have on my page:

```
<script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.2.2/mapbox.js"></script>
<style>

    body { 
    margin:0; 
    padding:0; 
    }
    #map { 
    position:absolute; 
    top:0; 
    bottom:0; 
    width:100%; 
    }
    .legend label,
    .legend span {
    display:block;
    float:left;
    height:15px;
    width:20%;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:9px;
    color:#808080;
    }

</style>
```

Then here's the BODY code I added for the mapbox elements.

```
<div id="legend" style="display:none;">
    <strong>The Title or Explanation of your Map</strong>
    <nav class="legend clearfix">
        <span style="background:#F1EEF6;"></span>
        <span style="background:#BDC9E1;"></span>
        <span style="background:#74A9CF;"></span>
        <span style="background:#2B8CBE;"></span>
        <span style="background:#045A8D;"></span>
        <label>0 - 20%</label>
        <label>40%</label>
        <label>60%</label>
        <label>80%</label>
        <label>100%</label>
        <small>Source: <a href="#">Name of source</a></small>
    </nav>
</div>
<div id="map"></div>

    <script>
    L.mapbox.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoibW1hcm1vbCIsImEiOiIzZTkxMDM4ZDI5MDZiMDY2MzFlOGQ4YzZiYmY2NmMzOSJ9.Cr8JtBNsYIl3LTxYZkaFPA';
      var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'mmarmol.2a3461fc');
      map.legendControl.addLegend(document.getElementById('legend').innerHTML);
    </script>
```

All other code is Bootstrap for the rest of my page. It seems like I have a CSS issue, or is it a js issue? Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: You **must** include the css asset of Mapbox. It's not optional. It sets style rules so that you map displays properly. Perhaps you can show an example with mapbox.css so we can exactly see what the problem is. Your first example doesn't have the code of the second example, it's just an embedded iframe url of your mapbox map at the mapbox server

Comment: Yep, I forgot to include that. [Here's the page](http://mcshanedev.com/canet/index-legend1a.html) with the mapbox CSS included.

Comment: @Maria: The links on this question are dead. Can you update the links or the question accordingly?